# How to make Prettier to ignore a certain tag or block of code in JSX/TSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, prettier, tsx

[image]

I use prettier for my React + Next.js project, I like it a lot but for the React interface it usually uses SVGs, whose parameters are irrelevant because is usually just a copy-paste from an external library or web.
I would like prettier to ignore the SVG formatting so that it stays on a single line and have a much cleaner code as it takes up a lot and is irrelevant.

Like this:

[image]

I have thought about creating a file where to put all the code of the SVGs and export them as components, but I would prefer just to be able to use them in literal form

Answer (score 0):

One option I found is using brackets to place a comment like this:

[image]

It would be nice if someone knows if it's possible to just add a certain tag,  in this case to the Prettier config and skip adding {/* prettier-ignore */} every time.